# How to make bash script ask you if you want to execute the next segment(part)?

Tags: bash

Soon as I execute the bash script. Given that I have

```
set -x
```

I will visually observe what is happening. But at certain parts, I want it to stop and ask me if I still want to continue executing the next lines.

I know about:

```
set -e
```

which simply ensures bash script exits on error, but I'd rather not use that. Rather I want to just divide my codes and make the bash script ask me every now and then if it should proceed or not.

Comment: i am hoping there is a line i can just insert in my bash script anywhere.. and it will break (exit) unless i enter "1" for example.

Comment: perhaps something like : read input .. eval(input) .. this way if i write exit.. it can exit.

Comment: If you want to use this in multiple places then it's better to write a function for that.And wherever you want the use intervention just call that function.

Comment: This is what i use to break the bash script : `read a; if [ "$a" == "1" ]; then exit; fi` - if i hit enter it continues. if i type 1 it exits.

Comment: Yeah you can say `exit 1`.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` is you are specifying that you are using `bash`.And one more thing if you say `exit 1` inside the function then it just exits the function not the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `read` for interactive scripts.

For example:

```
echo "Do you want to continue?(yes/no)"
read input
if [ "$input" == "yes" ]
then
echo "continue"
fi
```

And you can have your if conditions to execute further based on the `input` provided.

**EDIT**

If you want to use this in multiple places then you can create a funtion and call wherever you want the user intervention.

Answer (score 3):

To get a confirmation to continue, the **`read` builtin** of bash can be used. But if yoy want to do that every coule of lines, you do not want to insert more than a line in every place you need it.

Also, you do not want to **enter a full answer** whether the program should go on or not - like "yes" or "y"; **Pressing enter** should be enough to go on; And to stop, **Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>** is easy and clear enough.

But now you add all these confirmation checks to your code - what if you want to just run it a couple of times, with **no need for the checks**? Right, would be good to be able to **switch it off**. We use a variable for this.

You could write a **function** that can be added on lines in between for that:

```
#!/bin/bash

#useConfirm=true - comment out the line below like this to disable confirmation
useConfirm=true

confirm() {
   [ "$useConfirm" = true ] && read -p "Proceed? (Enter) - (^C to abort)"
}

echo a
confirm
echo b
echo c
confirm
echo d
```

Comment: Why you want a `confirm` function and `useConfirm` variable for this.Instead you can just say `read` press enter to continue otherwise press ctrl+c.Simple

Comment: I mean `echo "Continue";read;echo "Continue";read`.This is enough I guess.If he wants to continue he can press enter otherwise ctrl+c.

Comment: The `useConfirm` variable allows to disable all the confirm calls at once. The prompt text is needed for explanation, but should not be part of the line to insert for a check.